# Replace new lines with dashes under specific condition

Tags: regex, awk, sed

I am trying to write a command (sed/awk) for replacing a newline with a dash under the following conditions:

This should not be replaced with a dash because there is no new line in the CSV:

```
X00000;111111;1111111111;This is just a text
```

Anyway, in this example, the new line should be replaced with a dash:

```
X00000;111111;1111111111;This is a longer text which contains a 
new line sign.
```

The output of the replacement should look like this:

```
X00000;111111;1111111111;This is a longer text which contains a - new line sign.
```

Edit: This should also work for lines like this:

```
X00000;111111;1111111111;"This is a longer text which contains a
new line sign
or even more

or a line that even contains only a new line sign

"
```

In this case, the following output is expected:

```
X00000;111111;1111111111;"This is a longer text which contains a - new line sign - or even more - - or a line that even contains only a new line sign - "
```

Comment: Is the number of columns in the CSV fixed to 4? Can the newline be anywhere? Can there be multiple newlines?

Comment: Yes, the number of columns is fixed to 4, the newline can only be in the last column. Thanks

Comment: Please post expected output.  Should blank line be just like `-  -  -`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an option using `sed`:

```
$ cat file
X00000;111111;1111111111;This is just a text
X00000;111111;1111111111;This is a longer text which contains a 
new line sign.
X00000;111111;1111111111;"This is a longer text which contains a
new line sign
or even more

or a line that even contains only a new line sign

"
```

```
$ sed  ':a;$bc;N;s/\n/ - /;ba;:c;s/ - X00000;/\nX00000;/g' file
X00000;111111;1111111111;This is just a text
X00000;111111;1111111111;This is a longer text which contains a  - new line sign.
X00000;111111;1111111111;"This is a longer text which contains a - new line sign - or even more -  - or a line that even contains only a new line sign -  - "
```

**Explanation:**

```
sed '
    :a                         # Create a label a
    $bc                        # If it is last line, branch to label c
    N                          # Append next line to pattern space
    s/\n/ - /                  # Remove the \n and replace it with -
    ba                         # Keep repeating above steps until file is complete
    :c                         # Our label c. Do the following when end of file is reached
    s/ - X00000;/\nX00000;/g   # We do this substitution to add newlines where needed. 
' file
```

Answer (score 1):

Using awk you can do:

```
awk -F ';' 'NF<4{print p, "-", $0;p="";next} p{print p} {p=$0} END{if (p) print p}' file.csv
X00000;111111;1111111111;This is just a text
X00000;111111;1111111111;This is a longer text which contains a  - new line sign.
```

Comment: Thats very close to the solution but the newline is still there so it looks like this:

`X00000;111111;1111111111;This is a longer text which contains a   
- new line sign.`

Comment: Sorry, I am havíng troubles using the formatings, I want the newline to be deleted and replaces with a dash - using your command there simply is a dash in the new line but the newline still is there.

Comment: You can see output of my awk in my answer. There is no newline before or after dash. Where exactly are you getting extra newline?

Comment: There are still new lines, when the input text has two new lines, but it's ok if i run the script several times.

Comment: Can there be more than 1 new lines also? Its better if provide a good sample of date in your question so that I can understand it better.

Comment: So this multi line text is always in quotes or is it optional?

Comment: unfortunately this is optional

Comment: Oh ok I need to run for a meeting, I will make an attempt to solve your updated question after coming back.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an `awk` that just join all together.

```
awk '{printf (NR==1||!/X00000/)?$0:RS $0} END {print ""}' file
X00000;111111;1111111111;This is just a text
X00000;111111;1111111111;This is a longer text which contains a new line sign.
X00000;111111;1111111111;"This is a longer text which contains anew line signor even moreor a line that even contains only a new line sign"
```

It will not add the `-`